# checking if a @variable.method exists?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm using datamapper to store to a database. immediately after the db is migrated none of the methods exist because there are no values

```
<input type="text" name="seed" value="<%= @seed.value unless @seed.respond_to(value)? %>"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not too sure I follow your question, but it looks like this:

```
@seed.value unless @seed.respond_to(value)?
```

Should be this:

```
@seed.value if @seed.respond_to?(:value)
```

`respond_to?` is the name of the method, so put the question mark in the correct place.  Also, you want to pass a Symbol `:value` rather than the variable/method call `value` as the argument.

Finally, that should be `if`, not `unless`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to debug the variable to see what information (if any) it holds

```
<%= debug @seed %>
```

Comment: sorry im not using rails, that was a typo for the tags